# How do you calculate if 2 lines are facing toward or away?

Tags: math, geometry, lines, bezier, curves

Given the 4 points describing 2 lines, how do you quickly calculate if line A is facing towards or away from line B?

[image]

---

Similarly, how to check if line A is towards or away from quadratic bezier curve B?

[image]

Comment: It depends on how the lines are specified, e.g, origin point + angle, or start point and end point, or some other method ?...

Comment: Start point, end point is available ... angle can be trivially calculated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the dot product of the unit vector of the candidate line and the unit normal pointing in the direction you wish for the other (there are two unit normal vectors).

If the dot product is positive, it's "away"; "towards" is negative.

If you don't know vectors, get an intro text and read up on them.